# Where is ready queue located in a computer system ? Main memory, Secondary memory or some other location?

Tags: memory, operating-system, scheduler

I had a question in my college's mid-semester examination of Operating Systems. The question goes like this:
Which schedular is associated with selecting processes from the main memory?
A) Long Term Schedular
B) Short Term Schedular
C) Medium Term Schedular
D) Job Schedular
However, **my asked question** is not directly linked to this, but still could someone answer ? Although, if you wish to answer the question which is metioned above, **please provide a reason to support your answer**. *Your contribution is appreciated* !

Answer (score 1):

main memory and cache are the places for queues for obvious reason of efficiency. **the time to access something from secondary memory is magnitude of high from that of main memory or cache**. **Usually systems maintain ready queue in main memory**

A **long term scheduler** is responsible to manage the ready queue: a queue which contains runnable processes. when a process is created it is usually(not for all systems) submitted to ready queue. long term scheduler manage this submission so that ready queue should not exceed from some specific threshold value. this is necessary to reduce the burden on OS. you can say it as admission scheduler which maintains the concurrency level in system

medium term: leave it blank here for clarity

**short term scheduler:** when some event happens which interreupts the running process the short term schedule comes in play. It selects some process from ready queue based on some criteria, to dispatch the process. thats why it is also called dispatcher which is most frequently used. dispatching in simple words mean that process is assigned CPU

**Medium term:** long term puts process in reay queue and short term puts "process on CPU" why there is need for any other scheduler. the problem arise when system becomes low on memory; so there should be a scheduler to pick some process from ready queue and place this in secondary memory(hard disk) and vice versa.

if still not clear read wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_%28computing%29

**job scheduler** A job scheduler is a computer application for controlling unattended background program execution (commonly called batch processing)

you should not mix process scheduling with job scheduling. check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_scheduler for more details

Comment: So, the answer to the above asked question is Short-term scheduler ? I understand that it would be better to put ready queue in main memory so that it can be accessed in less time. Is ready queue located in main memory, generally ?

Comment: yes generally located in main memory but can be in fast cache as these are the most extensively used structures